# infinity marquee cuts off at the end

Tags: css

My sandbox in [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/Lrt0f681/1/)

Im trying to show an infinity background marquee without cutting off the end of the bars. I have been playing on `@keyframes scroll {}` for hours and couldn't fix it right.

The goal is to display the marquee to play in the center at the starting point (not from the right)

AND

when the "End" shows up on the right, the "Start" shows right next to the "End" from the right.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3d4b57;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
  padding: 0;
}

.marquee2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  animation: scroll 15s linear infinite;
  padding: 0;
}

.img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vw;
  background-color: #27323b;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.img2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vw;
  background-color: #323f4a;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="marquee">
    <div class="img2 inline">
      <div class="left">start</div>
      <div class="right">end</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marquee2">
    <div class="img1 inline">
      <div class="left">start</div>
      <div class="right">end</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have 2 marquee elements because you want to be able to use it with different speeds using the same code?

Comment: Yes and when the webpage loads there are two elements centered on the starting point and to show "End" right next to the "Start" on the right to loop the motion.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem should be simple, you can use `animation-delay` with negative value to "start it in negative time".

The second problem cannot be done with pure CSS unless you only want the background to be there. If you only wanted background, you could do it with an `::after`, but if there should be anything more really, you need to duplicate the element twice in the HTML document and animate the two of them next to each other. This will allow you to animate the first all the way to `-100%`, while using the second one to be visible, then move the first one to `left: 100%` while the second one is moving out of the screen to the left. In the code I changed it to show with two marquees that follow each other. So if you need two different marquees, you need two pairs of two.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3d4b57;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: -12.5s; // start at 50
  padding: 0;
}

.marquee2 {
  animation-delay: -7.5s; // start at -50
}

.img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vw;
  background-color: #27323b;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.img2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vw;
  background-color: #323f4a;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="marquee">
    <div class="img2 inline">
      <div class="left">start</div>
      <div class="right">end</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marquee marquee2">
    <div class="img1 inline">
      <div class="left">start</div>
      <div class="right">end</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that's a good start from there. I just want these to move in a parallax effect. Is it possible if I could add another marquee with a different speed?

Comment: Yes, you need two pairs of marquees and when you change the speed, you also need to change the delays